# Status code 401

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-status-code-401

I have a 401 Error to HTTP Request - 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) on console.log, how I can solve this problem?

```
GET somelink 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)
api.js:35 Error: UNAUTHORIZED
at Request.<anonymous> (client.js:423)
at Request../node_modules/component-emitter/index.js.Emitter.emit (index.js:133)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (client.js:735)
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: where are doing requests? BTW 401 means you are not authorized to access that resource either you have wrong credentials or you are not sending them correctly

Answer (score 0):

The error answers your issue,you are unauthorized to make this request. Either the type of data being sent is incorrect or permissions need to be set from the sever side.